# How to pass multiple target_id/values field using entity reference prepopulate?

Tags: entities

I read the documentation and saw that this is possible: `node/add/page?field_bar=1,2,3`

But how do you code this? I wanted to pass multiple target id, not just one.

I tried this code but this only passes 1 value which is the first field value.

```
<?php
$l = l( t('Create Package'), 'node/add/package',   array('query' => array('field_product_food' =>$node->field_product_food['und'][0]['target_id'])  ));
echo $l; 
?>
```

I also tried using an array loop like this:

```
<?php
$nids = array();
foreach ($node->field_product_food[$node->language] as $index => $item) {
$nids[] = $item['target_id'];
}
$l = l( t('Create Package'), 'node/add/package',   array('query' => array('field_product_food' =>$nids)  ));
echo $l; 
?>
```

but the result is not like the example from the documentation.

Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to create this link: `node/add/page?field_bar=1,2,3`

You need to put a comma between each nid, so [implode()](http://php.net/implode) is what you want.

E.g.

```
$l = l( t('Create Package'), 'node/add/package',   array('query' => array('field_product_food' => implode(',', $nids))  ));
```

Comment: OMG it worked! you're a life saver.. thank you my friend.. :D